# spring boot how to handle fault tolerance in async method?

Tags: spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I have a caller to distribute work to multiple async tasks:

```
public class Caller{
    public boolean run() {
        for (int i = 0: i< 100; i++) {
            worker.asyncFindOrCreate(entites[i]);
        }
        return true;
    }

public class Worker{
    @Autowired
    Dao dao;

    @Async
    public E asyncFindOrCreate(User entity) {
        return dao.findByName(entity.getName).elseGet(() -> dao.save(entity));
    }
}
```

If we have 2 same entities:
with the synchronized method, the first one will be created and then the second one will be retrieved from the existing entity;
with async, the second entities might pass the `findByName` and go to `save` because the first entity hasn't been saved yet, which cause the `save` of the second entity throws unique identifier error.

Is there a way to add some fault tolerance mechanic to have some features like retry and skipAfterRetry, in particular for database operations.

Answer (score 0):

In this special case you should convert your array to a map. Use the name property as a key, so there will be no duplicated entries.

However, if this method also can be called by multiple threads (ie. it's in a web-server) or there are multiple instances running it's still not fail-safe.

In generic, you should let the DB to check the uniqueness. There is no safest/easiest way to do that. Put the save method inside a try-catch block and check/handle the unique identifier exception.